# Docker instalation failed on windows server 2016 datacenter

Tags: windows, docker

I'm trying to install docker at this VM

[image]

But I'm getting the following error:

[image]

According to [this documentation](https://www.globo.tech/learning-center/windows-server-standard-vs-datacenter/), windows server 2016 datacenter  does support docker.

Also in the [microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started-19/editions-comparison-19), at least for the 2019 it is specified that containerization it is supported, is there a different version for this OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation, the problem seems to be Docker Desktop, according to this article [Build and run your first Docker Windows Server container](https://www.docker.com/blog/build-your-first-docker-windows-server-container/), for Windows server you need to execute the installation through the command line:

Once Windows Server 2016 is running, log in, run Windows Update to ensure you have all the latest updates and install the Windows-native Docker Engine directly (that is, not using “Docker for Windows”). Run the following in an Administrative PowerShell prompt:

```
Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Force
Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force
Restart-Computer -Force
```

Docker Engine is now running as a Windows service, listening on the default Docker named pipe. For development VMs running (for example) in a Hyper-V VM on Windows 10, it might be advantageous to make the Docker Engine running in the Windows Server 2016 VM available to the Windows 10 host:

**Open firewall port 2375**

`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="docker engine" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=2375`

**Configure Docker daemon to listen on both pipe and TCP (replaces docker --register-service invocation above)**

```
Stop-Service docker
dockerd --unregister-service
dockerd -H npipe:// -H 0.0.0.0:2375 --register-service
Start-Service docker
```

The Windows Server 2016 Docker engine can now be used from the VM host by setting DOCKER_HOST:

```
$env:DOCKER_HOST = "<ip-address-of-vm>:2375"
```